# Hyperledger Fabric - sendTransactionProposal() commits block to the ledger?

Tags: java, sdk, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am currently invoking my (hyperledger-fabric) networks' chaincode following [this](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk/blob/master/java/src/main/java/org/example/chaincode/invocation/InvokeChaincode.java) using my own chaincode. The line which sends the transaction is this :

```
Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = channelClient.sendTransactionProposal(request);
```

It works fine and the ledger is updated whenever I invoke a transaction.

My question is : Why does this code update the ledger ? Since **it only includes the proposal transaction**? Shouldn't the client send a transaction containing the former proposal responses in order to update the world state/blockchain? 
Another example, which (as expected) initially collects the proposal responses and then sends the transaction is [this](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/hyperledger-fabric-java-sdk-for-tls-enabled-fabric-network/). The two lines sending the transaction are :

```
Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);

CompletableFuture<TransactionEvent> cf = channel.sendTransaction(responses);
```

I used this code aswell and the result is the same (successfully updated ledger).

Any help?

Comment: Your second example is definitely the right way to get proposals and submit them to the orderer. The first example you gave will not submit the proposals to the orderer and so will not commit anything to the blockchain, so nothing will be updated. You can check the peer logs afterward to see that no blocks are committed for the first example but the second example should show blocks being committed in the peer logs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using [ChannelClient](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk/blob/master/java/src/main/java/org/example/client/ChannelClient.java) and not [Channel](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/Channel.java) to send the TransactionProposal. The first one sends the transaction on its own after the proposal request! (inside sendTransactionProposal(...) function)

Comment: I see. ChannelClient is one of their samples classes, not part of the java SDK. Talk about confusing giving it the same method names and actually doing something different. I see that that sample has been archived as well. It looks pretty old specifying fabric java sdk 1.0